# how to get misfire jobs by query quartz tables?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

i wanna to write a SQL script to get the misfire jobs,
There is some tables like QRTZ_TRIGGERS,
how can i implement the sql? 
maybe compare next_fire_time + misfireThreshold< now()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes something like this:

```
SELECT TRIGGER_NAME
FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS
WHERE NOT (MISFIRE_INSTR = -1)
  AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME < 1345050693000 
  AND TRIGGER_STATE = 'WAITING'
```

Basically you ask for all waiting triggers with `NEXT_FIRE_TIME` parameter far in the past. How far? Quartz assumes all triggers that are more than [`org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold`](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html) late are misfired. By default Quartz treats trigger as misfired if it was scheduled to run more than a minute ago. So take:

```
new Date() - 60 * 1000 * 1000
```

See [`StdJDBCConstants`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.1.5/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/StdJDBCConstants.java) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Column "TRIGGER_STATE" shows the state of each job, including MISFIRED ones:

```
SELECT *
FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS
WHERE TRIGGER_STATE = 'MISFIRED'
```

I'd also like to suggest to run this query

```
SELECT TRIGGER_STATE, COUNT(*)
FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS
GROUP BY TRIGGER_STATE
ORDER BY TRIGGER_STATE
```

during a few minutes intervals, to see a more dynamic behavior of the triggering mechanism.

Comment: how did u get to this query.. ? I am not able to open logs for Quartz query.. in my web application.. can you please help me out with that ?

Comment: by checking the QRTZ_TRIGGERS table contents directly. Can you find it in your DB?

Comment: oh.. i mean to say... how did you get this query from the application? more specifically.. u must have opened the logs in the application to get the exact query... how did u do that?

Comment: It was already there in the application under test. You probably need to adjust log4j configuration and define the logging level for quartz.